# PdfImage constructor error using PoDoFo library

Tags: c++, podofo

I started working with PoDoFo a few weeks ago. Previously, I have worked with cairomm. I am creating a PDF output with PoDoFo in Visual Studio 2022 but when trying to insert a PNG image a have compilation error regarding PdfImage constructor.

I am trying the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <podofo/podofo.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace PoDoFo;

void PrintLogo(const string_view& filename) {
    PdfMemDocument document;
    PdfPainter painter;
    PdfFont* font;

    string imageFile = "C:\\image.png";

    try {
        auto& page = document.GetPages().CreatePage(PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize(PdfPageSize::A4));
        painter.SetCanvas(page);

        font = document.GetFonts().SearchFont("Arial");
        if (!font) throw runtime_error("Invalid handle");

        painter.TextState.SetFont(*font, 18);
        painter.GraphicsState.SetFillColor(PdfColor(1, 0.5, 0.5));
        painter.GraphicsState.SetStrokeColor(PdfColor(1, 0.0, 0.0));

        PdfImage image(&document);
        //image.Load(imageFile);
        //painter.DrawImage(70.0, page.GetRect().Height - image.GetHeight(), &image);
       
        painter.FinishDrawing();

        document.Save(filename);
    }

    catch (PdfError& e) {
        try {
            painter.FinishDrawing();
        }
        catch (...) {
      
        }
        throw e;
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        const string pdfFilename = "C:\\TestPoDoFo001.pdf";

        PrintLogo(pdfFilename);
    }
    catch (PdfError& err) {
        err.PrintErrorMsg();
        return static_cast<int>(err.GetCode());
    }

    cout << endl << "Created a PDF file: TestPoDoFo001.pdf" << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And I am obtaining the following compilation error:

```
Build started at 4:00 PM...
1>------ Build started: Project: PodofoTest1, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>PodofoTest1.cpp
1>C:\Users\FABIANESPINO\source\repos\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1.cpp(25,23): error C2665: 'PoDoFo::PdfImage::PdfImage': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
1>C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfImage.h(221,1):
1>could be 'PoDoFo::PdfImage::PdfImage(const PoDoFo::PdfImage &)'
1>  C:\Users\FABIANESPINO\source\repos\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1.cpp(25,23):
1>  'PoDoFo::PdfImage::PdfImage(const PoDoFo::PdfImage &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument *' to 'const PoDoFo::PdfImage &'
1>      C:\Users\FABIANESPINO\source\repos\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1.cpp(25,24):
1>      Reason: cannot convert from 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument *' to 'const PoDoFo::PdfImage'
1>C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\podofo\main\PdfImage.h(169,5):
1>or       'PoDoFo::PdfImage::PdfImage(PoDoFo::PdfObject &)'
1>  C:\Users\FABIANESPINO\source\repos\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1.cpp(25,23):
1>  'PoDoFo::PdfImage::PdfImage(PoDoFo::PdfObject &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument *' to 'PoDoFo::PdfObject &'
1>C:\Users\FABIANESPINO\source\repos\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1\PodofoTest1.cpp(25,23):
1>while trying to match the argument list '(PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument *)'
1>Done building project "PodofoTest1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 4:00 PM and took 02.118 seconds ==========
```

Could you helping me showing the right way to include a PNG file using PoDoFo? I haven't found much PoDoFo examples as starting point.

Kind regards.

Comment: Please copy the text of the error message from the Output Tab and not the Errors list. Besides the Output Tab being in a better format for copying and pasting I expect it has more information that can help solve the problem. The full error message should explain why the parameters you are using are not correct.

Comment: Is this the exact code that returns that error or is the error from your own project and the attached code is just an MRE? I ask because I don't see any references to lines in the error code and at first glance, the code in the MRE seems to match what I saw on GitHub.

Comment: ***Reason: cannot convert from 'PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument *' to 'const PoDoFo::PdfImage'*** Are very different things. I don't know if you are missing an include or this code just doesn't work with your version.

Comment: @drescherjm podofo.h already includes it, from what I saw on GH. Also, the error would be different if the type is unknown or incomplete.

Comment: Would using a different constructor potentially resolve the issue?

Comment: @RenzoFabián OK, this makes more sense now. The initial error you posted didn't mention an ambiguity, which is an entirely different thing. This is why you must **NEVER** truncate error messages to what you *think* is useful. But now you know it's best to post it all and let us decide if we ignore any info or not, rather than posting an incomplete message :) So back to the error. Have you tried `PdfImage image(&document, nullptr);` to try to reduce the chance of ambiguity? (also I think you don't have the latest version of the PoDoFo SDK)

Comment: The same error using `PdfImage image(&document, nullptr);` .  I have this PoDoFo version: `podofo:x64-windows                                0.10.3              PoDoFo is a library to work with the PDF file fo...`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems I was looking in an older version which explains why the error seemed confusing. Indeed, like the examples you found online, [the old one](https://github.com/mekentosj/podofo/blob/master/src/doc/PdfImage.h) was `PdfImage( PdfDocument* pParent, const char* pszPrefix = NULL );` with an optional parameter which is why `image(&document);` [*used*](https://sourceforge.net/p/podofo/mailman/message/30496561/) to work.

The [updated PoDoFo `PdfImage`](https://github.com/podofo/podofo/blob/master/src/podofo/main/PdfImage.h) no longer has the old constructor with an optional second parameter. The new constructor is `PdfImage(PdfDocument& doc, const std::string_view& prefix);` and it's marked as `private`. So what you're trying shouldn't work anymore.

I haven't worked with PoDoFo but a brief check of [`PdfDocument`](https://github.com/podofo/podofo/blob/master/src/podofo/main/PdfDocument.cpp) shows this:

```
unique_ptr<PdfImage> PdfDocument::CreateImage(const string_view& prefix)
{
    return unique_ptr<PdfImage>(new PdfImage(*this, prefix));
}
```

So I'd venture a guess that you need to call it from `PdfDocument` (or in your case, `PdfMemDocument` since it's a child class) like so [`std::unique_ptr<PdfImage> image = document.CreateImage(prefix)`](https://github.com/podofo/podofo/blob/master/src/podofo/main/PdfDocument.h) (at least assuming you're using the latest version). When using the returned value, keep in mind it returns a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

As I said I haven't worked with this lib, so I can't test and tell you whether your code will actually work, since I'd say that converting the old lib to C++17 changed it quite a lot (as you can see in the 2 different GitHub sources: the main and the old unmaintained fork), so that'll be your homework and is an entirely different topic.

But the above solution should fix the compilation error addressed by your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the previous answer from @TheNomad:

This code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <podofo/podofo.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace PoDoFo;

void PrintLogo(const string_view& filename) {
    PdfMemDocument document;
    PdfPainter painter;
    PdfFont* font;

    string imageFile = "C:\\image.png";

    try {
        auto& page = document.GetPages().CreatePage(PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize(PdfPageSize::A4));
        painter.SetCanvas(page);

        font = document.GetFonts().SearchFont("Arial");
        if (!font) throw runtime_error("Invalid handle");

        painter.TextState.SetFont(*font, 18);
        painter.GraphicsState.SetFillColor(PdfColor(1, 0.5, 0.5));
        painter.GraphicsState.SetStrokeColor(PdfColor(1, 0.0, 0.0));
       
        auto image = document.CreateImage();
        image->Load(imageFile);
        painter.DrawImage(*image, 400.0, page.GetRect().Height - 50, 0.25, 0.25);
        painter.FinishDrawing();

        document.Save(filename);
    }

    catch (PdfError& e) {
        try {
            painter.FinishDrawing();
        }
        catch (...) {
      
        }
        throw e;
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        const string pdfFilename = "C:\\TestPoDoFo001.pdf";

        PrintLogo(pdfFilename);
    }
    catch (PdfError& err) {
        err.PrintErrorMsg();
        return static_cast<int>(err.GetCode());
    }

    cout << endl << "Created a PDF file: TestPoDoFo001.pdf" << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```